# How to schedule PS Query to export a query nightly with a dynamic file name?

Tags: peoplesoft

I'm in the process of setting up nightly query exports to provide to our 3rd party vendor.  I wrote a few queries that are scheduled to output every night

I have 2 questions about PS Query scheduling:

1) Are there any limitations to where I save the output files?  I'm curious if PS Query have the ability to save the CSV directly to a SFTP server?

2) Does PS Query have the ability to output a file with a dynamically generated file name?
For example: the vendor requires a datestamp on all their import files, so I need to schedule my query to output with a filename of *EE_JOBDATA_OUTPUT_20170714.xls*.

I've already named my query *EE_JOBDATA_OUTPUT*, but I am not how I can concatenate "_yyyymmdd.xls" to the filename

I appreciate any help/feedback/suggestions

cheers

Answer (score 0):

When you schedule the query you can select different output types and formats.  One output type option is "File", which would write to a location on your server.  You would need scripts or something to pick it up from there.

In PeopleTools 8.55 it looks like there are some newer output type options, one being "IB Node".  I have not tried this, but you might be able to setup an SFTP Node then run the query to that node.  Although that looks like it requires building a transformation as well.

If you need more control you may want to look at having it written into an App Engine or BI Publisher Report.  You can have an App Engine that calls a query if you want to be able to maintain the query itself online.